# Scrapy startproject command failed on import etree, Mac M1. The error message is: "symbol not found in flat namespace"

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml, apple-m1, xml.etree

I am trying to start a project using the Scrapy library, for a small webscraping project, but it fails on the import etree module. The exact error on the traceback is:

```
from .. import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myname/Desktop/scrapy_project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister'
```

I have tried uninstalling reinstalling Scrapy and lxml libraries using pip, pip3, conda, and brew. Each time I am faced with the same error when I try the scrapy shell command or scrapy startproject command on the terminal. I have even downloaded xcode using the

```
xcode-select --install
```

command, which did not seem to help either.

What exactly does the "symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister'" error mean? Any idea how to work around the etree library or get scrapy to work?
for reference I am working on a macbook pro m1 computer and running the project on Pycharm, using python 3.10.
Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try the older Python version? Scrapy does not officially support 3.10. Also, do not use the system Python and or Homebrew. Download python 3.9 from python.org, create a virtual environment and then install scrapy.

Comment: Install libxml2 and libxslt before installing lxml. See [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/5308).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with uninstalling lxml and reinstalling it with conda:

```
pip uninstall lxml
conda -c install lxml
```

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue, uninstall lxml:
`pip3 uninstall lxml`

then

`pip3 install lxml --no-cache-dir` it will force redownload and build wheel