# lxml fails to import, with error `symbol not found in flat namespace '_xsltDocDefaultLoader'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, apple-m1

With the code:

```
from lxml.etree import HTML, XML
```

I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/code/project/lxml-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lxml.etree import HTML, XML
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/.virtualenvs/project-venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): 
symbol not found in flat namespace '_xsltDocDefaultLoader'
```

I'm on a mac m1 chip.

I installed libxml2 and libxslt via brew.

I'm running python 3.11 inside of a virtualenv.

#### What I've tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing lxml with pip, and tried several different versions. (4.7.1 & 4.8.0 didn't compile. All of the 4.9.0,1,2 versions give me the above error)
- Installing libxml2 and libxslt via brew and then reinstalling python-lxml.
- Installing python-lxml via conda ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74596889/564872))

##### EDIT:

I posted this bug in lxml's bug report forum, and was notified that this is a highly-duplicated bug report of [Missing wheel for macos with M1 Edit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1913032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by cloning lxml, building it, and installing it via

```
pip install -e /path/to/lxml
```

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this issue with lxml 5.1.0 on an M1 Mac running Python 3.8. The issue went away when I installed lxml 4.9.4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue recently while trying to install the `python-docx` module within a 3.9 virtualenv on my laptop with the M1 Pro chip.

This answer helped solve my issue: [Unable to install python-docx (MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127779/unable-to-install-python-docx-macos)

Basically, you'd need to install the setuptools with pip within your virtualenv first and then try to install lxml with pip:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that sadly didn't work for me. It's a good thing to know tho!

Answer (score 0):

Removed lxml 5.1.0 and Installed lxml 4.9.4 solved my problem

Comment: This was already mentioned in a previous answer.